# Significado de 'telera'

Tags: definiciones, méxico

En cierta versión de [Don Juan Tenorio](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tDY7S7YUiY4) (hacia el min 2:15) dice el criado de don Juan:

> No presuma de toronja,
> de mandarina, ni pera,
> que quiso llegar a monja
> y no llegó ni a *telera*

El término *[telera](https://dle.rae.es/telera?m=form)* en ninguna de sus 10 acepciones me cuadran para darle sentido a la estrofa. Si acaso es otra la palabra, hay otra acepción usada en México, ya hace medio siglo... o el chiste viene por algún otro término, gracias por la aclaración

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como estamos hablando de comida, yo creo que [telera](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telera_(pan)) hace referencia al pan blanco. Básicamente, al decir '*y no llegó ni a telera*', significa que no tiene dinero ni para comprarse un pan.

Answer (score 1):

También me causaba curiosidad la estrofa e investigando un poco logré llegar a la conclusión que al referirse a "telera" se refiere a una tajada de pan blanco como el que se utiliza para preparar emparedados; el término "monja" hace referencia a un bocado de panadería tipo mojicón, rosca u otro pan dulce de mayor calidad